# Ext.LoadMask stays in background of the loading panel

Tags: background, sencha-touch, layer, masking, extjs

I try to show a loading mask while user waits for the panel to be shown.

I use Ext.LoadMask like :

```
loadingMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Loading..."});

loadingMask.show();
panel = new MyPanel();
panel .show();
```

and in panel's afterrender

```
this.listeners = {
        afterrender: function () {
        loadingMask.hide();
        }
}
```

But no loading mask is shown till panel comes and when I close panel I see the loading Mask.

I think this means my loading mask is running in background so I can't see it.

Is there solution you know for this issue ? This seems like a layer problem I think.

How can I make loading mask be shown on top and in panel's afterrender hide it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put MyPanel's show  function in delayedtask.
Then I put the unmask implementation in beforedestroy listener of MyPanel.
There should be some callback mechanism for this LoadMask thing i think.
When I put show following one and other layers get messed up.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
 Ext.onReady(function(){
            var loadingMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {
                msg: "Loading..."
            });

            loadingMask.show();
            var panel = new Ext.Panel({
                renderTo: 'div1',
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                title: 'MyPanel',
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: function(){
                        loadingMask.hide();
                    }
                }
            });         

        });
```

I've included the renderTo config option to tell Ext where to create the panel on the page. Apart from a couple of spelling mistake in your example, I think the main problem is that your afterrender handler is not firing because you are not attaching it to your panel object. You need to assign it as part of your config options. You are assigning your afterrender handler to 'this' which could quite possibly be the top level window object in your example.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your response.Actually I'm not using any divs in my app.I have various panels shown on index.html.I show and destroy or hide each one.I think maybe I need some call back mechanism to check if panel is rendered or somewhat and hide loading mask?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Are you saying that the afterrender event is not firing when you include it as part of the config? The afterrender event is effectively a callback.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

Add loading mask

```
Ext.getBody().mask('Loading...', 'x-mask-loading', false);
```

Remove loading mask

```
Ext.getBody().unmask();
```

Comment: Thanks Paul it is not exactly what i was looking for but pretty easy way to show and hide the mask.I use unmask in beforedestroy of the panel.